# laravel dynamic sub-domain and databases on nginx

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, laravel-5

Guys i need help in implementation of this functional on **Laravel** and **Nginx**.

### Goal:

- When users register, he enters the data in the form.
- After successful registration creates a subdomain and activate the
  migration that creates the database with its name
- After he be logged in it redirects to UserName.site-name.com

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAj8L.png)

Comment: We aren't here to write your code. Pose a specific problem such as "Why does this happen?". SO is here so you can ask about a problem, and is not a suitable place for asking us to write code/give you a tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must to allow this from DNS. Add a wildcard `*.site-name.com` to point to your server and from this point, all you have to do is to add virtual hosts.

Here is more info https://www.siteground.com/kb/how_to_add_a_wildcard_dns_record/

and then you may create some console commands that enables/create vhosts and restart nginx. you'll have to call them from the controller.

Answer (score 0):

You are not precise enough, but if you are trying to build a site farm, based on the same CMS engine or something like this, then please have a look at subdomain routing:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#route-group-sub-domain-routing

```
Route::group(['domain' => '{username}.site-name.com'], function () {
    //pseudocode
    $connection = DB::connection($username);
    CMSEngine::run($connection);
});
```